# What is the format when I get data from multiple checkboxs? Can I get a list?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, django-templates, google-cloud-datastore

I have a Kind Tag with property tagName, and in a html, I code like this

```
{% for tag in tags%}
    <input type="checkbox" name="tagName" value={{tag.tagName}}>{{tag.tagName}}
{% endfor%}
```

Now, In my python file, I try to do this:

```
tagNames = self.request.get('tagName')
```

I want a list that contain every choice user choose. But what I got seems not.
So.

1. how can I get a list of user choices using request.get()?
2. Is there any other ways? I am not familiar with django, I just import gae's template. Can I use gae's template to simplify
   this question?

Thank you!

Comment: Any help?I googled but can't find the answer.

Comment: Steven, you need to clarify what framework you are using here

Comment: @ClaudeVedovini I use webapp framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict

Looks like QueryDict.getlist(key, default) will get you what you want.

ie. self.request.getlist('tagName')

Comment: I guess you meant request.POST.getlist(...)

Comment: yeh, possibly.. I was assuming that it would be available via request.REQUEST.getlist() as well.

Comment: Yes, your answer may right. But I am new to GAE and I am using GAE template for all my project, I just won't bring dhango into my project because I can't hold it. To slove my problem, I change my model to a many-to-may relationship and I don't need to implement what I asked. I konw django is a better way, I will learn it next step. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're using the webapp framework, instead of `self.request.get()`, use `self.request.get_all('tagName')`, which will return a list of values.